next.js page doesn't return a html router,ssg
when I refresh the page,it work,network has html.But if I use next link to the page,network doesn't return html.In code I use getStaticProps and getStaticPaths.And when I run build,I can see the /server/pages has html
I had try router and link,both dont work

Please give more detailed description of your problem. Add the code or provide relavant images.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
